# Unload a query involving joins in Redshift

Tags: join, amazon-redshift, export-to-csv

I have to unload the output of a query that involves joining 4 tables. 2 of the 4 tables are pretty huge in size. I have tried to optimize this unload in numerous ways as stated below yet the query continues to run more than 10 hours on the cluster.

1. Removed `PARALLEL OFF` to unload happen parallelly
2. Used `PARQUET` to write the output in the optimized redshift friendly data format
3. Created temp table for the 2 massive table with the dist key as the same column being joined upon in the query.

Please let me know if there are any further ways we can optimize to unload the table efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: How long does the Select statement inside the UNLOAD take to run?  The unload cannot run faster than the select that makes the data.  I suspect that this is where the focus needs to be.  To understand this more info about the SELECT will be needed.

Comment: yes the unload was further split into individual joins of these 4 tables. It was identified that one of the joins was taking a very long time. Now the issue is that the joins are being performed on the dist key's, yet the join performed is of type HASH join. Is there a way to perform Merge join here?

Comment: If you look at the EXPLAIN plan do you see a large increase in rows at this join step?    Is it possible that this join is creating a lot of new rows.  What distribution are you seeing in the hash join in that is slow?   I wouldn't focus on merge vs hash as it isn't often the cause of very slow joins.  In general hash joins are fast enough, bad joins are slow.  Can you post the EXPLAIN plan for the query?

Comment: Actually we were able to optimize the join from hash to merge after adding sort keys, yet it didn't complete after 16hrs of runtime. So there must be another way to optimize the joins. Here is the explain plan: `XN Hash Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=552153.70..436587803095.27 rows=28626707649 width=158)
  Hash Cond: ("outer".x_id = "inner".y_id)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on table_a tjit  (cost=0.00..2220301.92 rows=222030192 width=116)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=441722.96..441722.96 rows=44172296 width=55)
        ->  XN Seq Scan on table_b tpp  (cost=0.00..441722.96 rows=44172296 width=55)`

Comment: This is what I was mentioning before - the issue is with the join, not the join type.  The explain plan shows that you are taking a 441K row table and joining it to a 222M rows table and this is resulting in 28B rows.  That's > 100X row count increase over the larger table which will be slow.  It is also 158 columns wide so this may be a lot of data.  There's a good chance that this query is "spilling" to disk - check stl_scan for the query and see if there is a lot of data read from "internal worktable" type names.  There's a fair chance that there is a missing join on condition in your query

Comment: Yes I thought there could be a disk spill, hence I removed temp table expressions and replaced them with actual sandbox tables to avoid disk spill. The query has a inner join on the dist key columns of these sandbox tables. So the question comes down to - is there no chance of joining these tables?

Comment: So I don't know the exact differences between your temp table and sandbox tables but I think the disconnect is on how and why disk spill happens during a join.  The join seems to be making many times more rows than the input tables.  This happens when many rows in the outer table match many rows of the inner table based on the join on conditions.  Not 1 to 1, not 1 to many or many to 1.   The type of join doesn't matter nor does the dist key.  Your join is exploding the amount of data by over 100 times and I suspect that this isn't what you are intending.

Comment: Likely causes for this increase in data are: missing join on clause, inequality join on clause, or duplicates in one or both of the source tables.  You could be trying to make a sparse matrix but I suspect this isn't the case as you are unloading and sparse matrices are used as a source in certain analytics.   I suspect you need to look at a limited set of the resulting data and see why so many rows are being produced.

Comment: Yes, it is true that a lot of rows in the inner table is matching with a lot of rows in the outer table. And we are observing an explosion in the number of rows as an output of the two joined tables based on the join on condition. But, why isn't redshift able to perform such a join. Upon running the job if it were a disk spill issue, the job would have failed with an error condition of 'disk spill'. But the job continues to run an eternity. I tried unloading a limited set of 2 days worth of data and it was completed within 19 mins runtime. But it fails for 1 month worth of data.

Comment: Redshift doesn't fail when it starts to spill to disk.  It will fail when disks fill up with spilled data and there is no more room left.  Queries that run in memory run quickly but queries running from disk (spilled data) run very slowly.  I don't have a lot of information about your cluster so this is just speculation base on past experience.  After this query is running for a while you will start to see the disk usage metrics for the cluster start to rise (as the disks get more and more full).  This will be slow but steady.  Your cluster is not big enough to work on 28B rows in memory.

Comment: Put differently - I suspect you have a cluster sized to work on data that is 100s of millions of rows but you are making data that is in the 10s of billions of rows.  Even though you are unloading the data you need to make it before you can write it out to S3.

Comment: You are right about the disk usage. Our cluster stays around 35% disk usage constantly. Upon running this query its usage goes upto ~47%. Which means it is spilling a lot of data to disk and is really slow. Is there any way to optimize suh queries? Queries that involve returning billions of rows?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to generate such a large amount of data.  The first direction I would look is at how the amount of data can be reduced by looking at how it is used down stream.  If an optimization can be found that doesn't require all this data it would speed things up.  If all of it is needed then I'd look at how much bigger a cluster would be needed to run this efficiently but that might be too expensive.  Can the data be generated in parts?  Where each part can fit in memory.  Expanding data to this degree is just an expensive operation.

Comment: So - 1) Our downstream required this data for 27 months. And the above explain plan is for just joining 1 month worth of data. So the more we reduce to parts, it becomes harder to cover the huge time range we need to unload. 2) Our cluster was already upgraded the previous month to RA3 with 6 nodes, and plus there are other prod jobs running on the cluster that would be affected by an upgrade for just one request. And also it would be expensive. So is there any other way to optimize this? Anything related to configurations or any other methods using AWS?

Comment: Expanding data 100 fold is expensive especially when it needs to use disk for temp storage.  I expect optimizing the join / query is your best bet.  Do you have a DISTINCT or GROUP BY in the query?  These may be hiding the extent to which the data is growing beyond what you really need.  All all the columns needed?  Saving memory by removing unneeded columns could help.

Comment: We don't have a `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY`, but all due to business requirements. We have already removed all un-necessary columns and only including around 8-10 required columns.

Comment: I bet reducing columns helped but not near enough.  Is the query still spilling?  I’d be happy to look at the query to see if I see any opportunities but given the explain plan it looks straight forward.  There may be a way to construct things that will spill less but no promises.  Redshift is good at distilling data down (analytics), not creating new data.

Comment: So after talking to our customer, we were able to perform a group by on the table causing the issue(having duplicate id's). But still the query doesnt seem to complete given that now we are joining on unique ID's.

Comment: Is the group by after the join or before?

Comment: We split the joins into individual joins by creating temp tables. So while creating temp table of the table having these duplicates we perform the group by on the duplicate column that we use for the join later. So in simple words, before the join.

Comment: And you grouped by only the columns used in the joins?

Comment: I grouped by, the joining column(having duplicates) and couple other columns. Are these other columns causing the issue?

Comment: Possibly or even likely.  When you group by you will get unique combinations of all the values in the group by list.  If there are lots of combos for each unique value of the join on column there can be a massive row increase.  If you post your query and desired results I can try to help find a path to what you want without the row increase

Comment: The query is complicated and stackoverflow limits the number of characters. So it all comes down to selecting the column to be joined and group by on that only inorder to make it unique. But we require other columns from that table as well, so it becomes mandatory to include them in groupby. Is there any way around?

Comment: I expected it was complicated and that the data model also has issues.  This happens a lot.  So the issue really comes down to what, in words, do you desire to create?  The columns in question have meanings and you want to extract some new data set from the tables.  There's a purpose to this, what is it?  Just exploding the data isn't a purpose, you want it to tell you something.  Will joining with the most recent X or top 3 Xs or ... give the insight?  Creating all combinations will be big and slow.  Sounds like your client hasn't thought through what they really want.

Comment: I work with clients on these issues all the time (small consultancy) and it is very common for clients to not really know why they want something or what they are going to do with it.  They often don't know the appropriate places to draw boundaries between tools in their workflows.  I don't know the situation at all but it "feels" familiar.  You need to ask questions and help them find a path to success but this path is likely not the one they are thinking of right now.

Comment: You speak my mind @BillWeiner. Our clients don't really understand the complexity involved behind the query. They gave a query that serves their purpose. Something you do after a SQL 101. But redshift's capability of handling the massive exploding join, is a limitation. But the compromise from their end is less on the query. The two tables in question here are an invoice table and a payments table. Every invoice has an invoice number that can have multiple payment transactions. Hence, join comes down to 1-to-N. So they want the transaction-level data and if we group, it becomes invoice level.

Comment: 1-N shouldn't cause a row explosion - there shouldn't be more rows created than invoices.  I'd look to see if there are data issues going on or a missing aspect to the query.  Redshift doesn't enforce uniqueness - could they have duplicate invoice ids?  Is the invoice table type-2 (all updates to the invoices are saved but only the last one should be used)?  Do invoice ids get reused / recycled after some number of years and a join on clause is needed to ensure that they right matches are being made?  (yes all things I have seen in client data)

Comment: So I don't think the query can be altered here as they insist on getting the data returned by it. So is there any other way to do this? We tried extracting individual tables to an S3 and then joining using Spark but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd investigate why the join is N-to-M, not 1-to-N as they think.  This could lead to a root cause discovery.  If they really want a massive N-to-M join that generates tens of billions of rows I'd point out the non-sustainability of such a process - as N and M grow this will grow exponentially.  A trillion rows is not that far away.   There's a problem here and brute forcing it will just move the issue a little further down the road and will bite you then.

Comment: As for brute force idea - 1) A Redshift cluster big enough to hold the query result in memory will speed things up greatly but won't make this instantaneous and will cost a pretty penny.  This cluster can be fired up just when this output needs to be produced.  2) Break the query up into parts (1000) and create the output for each part in a separate query.  Since this is an unload put the files (uniquely named) in the same S3 "folder" and they look like they are part of the same unload.  Each part should complete in reasonable time but running all the parts still won't be quick.

Comment: Upside for #2 - it is not clear to me that the client has seen the output of this process even once (correct me if I'm wrong).  Showing them just one part of the output and asking them if this meets their needs (like pushing it through some downstream process) could reveal that this really isn't what they want.